# Playlist not playing

Tags: c#, .net, wmp, wmplib

I made an application in C# using WinForms for desktop. I added the WMP library. If I want to play a single file (video or audio) I just do `reproductor.URL = filePath` and it plays automatically (being reproductor the WMP added in the form).
Now I want to play a playlist, so I did:

```
curPlaylist = reproductor.playlistCollection.newPlaylist("curPlaylist");

        string[] filesArray = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\playlist", "*.mp3");

        foreach (string file in filesArray)
        {
            WMPLib.IWMPMedia media = reproductor.newMedia(file);
            curPlaylist.appendItem(media);
        }

        reproductor.currentPlaylist = curPlaylist;
```

and nothing happens, it is not playing any file.

I tried `reproductor.Ctlcontrols.play();` but still nothing. If I count the elements in the playlist it says 3 (there are 3 files in the playlist folder so this is correct).

I tried also to play the first element of the playlist `reproductor.Ctlcontrols.playItem(reproductor.currentPlaylist.get_Item(1));` and again nothing happens.

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't have any issue running this code.  Are you sure filesArray is being populated?

Comment: @NathanChampion yes, filesArray is populated, and I also don't have any issue running this code, I get no error. Buy it doesn't play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code is right. This is the correct way to play a playlist. Why didn't work previously? May be some driver issue, may be Visual Studio, may be some application that didn't release de audio driver. I Closed VS, restarted PC, and worked perfectly.